# How to return a Null/Zero/0 value with a COUNT function and a WHERE Clause

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I would like to `COUNT` all records from Table 2 with a `WHERE` criteria for each record that matches the primary key in Table 1. For example,

```
SELECT Table1.PrimaryID, Table1.Address, COUNT(Table2.Tenants)
FROM Table2 LEFT JOIN Table1 ON Table2.ForeignID = Table1.PrimaryID
WHERE (Table2.Status = "Single")
GROUP BY Table1.PrimaryID, Table1.Address
```

However, if there are no  matching records, the SQL will return nothing. I have tried the `Nz` function, which can replace Null values with whatever is specified, **but Null is not returned by a `WHERE` clause if nothing satisfies its criteria.**

As a workaround, I've ditched the `WHERE` clause in favor of a `SUM` and `IIF` statement as so:

```
SELECT Table1.PrimaryID, Table1.Address, SUM(IIF(Table2.Tenants="Single",1,0))
FROM Table2 LEFT JOIN Table1 ON Table2.ForeignID = Table1.PrimaryID
GROUP BY Table1.PrimaryID, Table1.Address
```

Is my workaround correct for my scenario? Are there any alternatives for returning a 0 value in a `COUNT` and `WHERE` clause situation? Thank you!

Comment: You may have a point... an 'INNER JOIN` may be more appropriate because I only want records with IDs that match completely

Answer (score 2):

You can use a subquery to calculate the count:

```
SELECT Table1.PrimaryID, Table1.Address, (SELECT Count(*) FROM Table2 WHERE Table2.ForeignID = Table1.PrimaryID AND Table2.Tenants="Single") As CountOfTable2
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Table1.PrimaryID, Table1.Address
```

If Table1.PrimaryID is unique for table 1, you can remove the group by.

Depending on other circumstances, your `Sum(Iif(` approach might be better. I use that one if I'm counting for multiple different conditions, as it avoids needing to write multiple subqueries.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! In both methods, `SELECT`-ing these 0 fields in a different query continues to return nothing. Argh... I'll probably have to subquery or `SUM` + `IIF` for each subsequent query.

Comment: @Plaxerous If you mean: querying off this query, it depends on what you're doing exactly. You can likely use subqueries again, but as said, `Sum(IIf(` is fine too and sometimes preferable.

Answer (score 1):

Your first version is basically right, the tables are just backwards:

```
SELECT Table1.PrimaryID, Table1.Address, COUNT(Table2.Tenants)
FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN
     Table2
     ON Table2.ForeignID = Table1.PrimaryID AND
        Table2.Status = "Single"
GROUP BY Table1.PrimaryID, Table1.Address
```

To be honest, I'm not sure if MS Access supports this ANSI-standard construct.  It is easily adjusted using a subquery:

```
SELECT Table1.PrimaryID, Table1.Address, COUNT(Table2.Tenants)
FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT Table2.*
      FROM Table2
      WHERE Table2.Status = "Single"
     ) as table2
     ON Table2.ForeignID = Table1.PrimaryID            
GROUP BY Table1.PrimaryID, Table1.Address
```

Comment: Access does support it, but only if you use parentheses: opening parenthesis after `ON`, closing after `"single"`. Imo it's more simple and thus preferable above your second solution, but the second one can be represented by the query builder, while the first one can't.